# It's about probability and I dont know how to start given 2k people formed from n couples.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, combinations

A group of $2k$ people is to be formed from $n$ couples, $k,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $2k \leq n$. What is the probability that

(a) there are exactly $k$ couples in such a group?

(b) no couples are included?

(c) exactly two couples are included in such a group?

I have tried to answer (a)
$\frac{{n \choose k}}{{n \choose 2k}}$. I don't know if this makes sense? And I really dont have any idea for (b) and (c).

Comment: Your answer for $a)$ is almost correct.  There are $\binom nk$ ways to choose $k$ couples from among $n$.  Once we have chosen the $k$ couples, there are no further choices to make; we know which $2k$ people are chosen.  Now we must divide by the number of ways to choose $2k$ people from $2n$.  That isn't $\binom n{2k}$, but ....?

Comment: Instead of n, should I replace it with 2n?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Here's a hint for starting the other two parts.  What can you say if exactly $m$ men are chosen?  (I am assuming that each couple comprises a man and a woman.)

Comment: There are actually 2C1 ways to choose men from n couples. Am I right? Does it imply that there are 2^{k} ways to choose them?

Comment: Not all all.  What you've said makes no sense to me.  Surely the number of ways to choose $m$ men from $n$ must depend on $m$ and $n$.

Comment: For the second part, observe that you must choose one representative from each of $2k$ couples.

Comment: Does it have to be (n)(n-2)...(n-2k) from choosing one representative from the group?